# how search for a data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem with retrieving data.
In the code below I'm saving data to db:

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
private DatabaseReference databaseReference = database.getReference(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());

databaseReference.child("age").setValue(sbAge.getProgress());
    databaseReference.child("status").setValue(spStatus.getSelectedItem().toString());

if(rbFemaleMe.isChecked())
{
    databaseReference.child("sex").setValue("Female");
}
else if(rbMaleMe.isChecked())
{
    databaseReference.child("sex").setValue("Male");
}
```

here is my database:
[db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjFWU.png)

How can I get all user with age = 27?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `equalTo()` method allows us to filter based on exact matches. As is the case with the other range queries, it will fire for each matching child node. For example, we can use the following query to find all user which have age of 27:

```
databaseReference.orderByChild("age").equalTo(27).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
        System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getKey());
    }

    // ...
});
```

Its is working fine for me hopes it will help..
For more go [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data)

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use custom model for getting the desired data.

```
databaseReference.orderByChild("age").equalTo(27).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        result = dataSnapshot.getValue();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
});
```

Try this, Hope this helps